# Laravel 5: проверка ввода Validator

Tags: laravel, валидация

В качестве логина пользователь может ввести либо *e-mail*,

либо телефон в формате *+7 (999) 999-99-99*.

Как задать правило в контроллере?

```
$rules = array(
        'login' => 'required|email,phone',
        'password' => 'required',
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Стандартными средствами не получится. Нужно писать свое правило валидации. Свое правило пишется, через объект Валидатора, вызывая метод after и передавая ему функцию callback.

```
$rules = [
    'login' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required',
    ];

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

//фунция, с описание своего правила
$validator->after(function($validator) {
    //Получаешь массив с входными данными
    $input = $validator->getData();
    //Строишь самостоятельную логику проверка данных
    //Делаешь условие на ошибку, если условие выполняется вызываешь метод error() для валидатора и добавляешь текст ошибки.
    if (условие на ошибку) {
         $validator->errors()->add('login', 'неверный формат');
    }
}
```